Why am i getting wrong answer? What is wrong with my solution?
Question -
After selling 10 candles a man earns a profit of the selling price of 3 pens.
While selling 10 pens, a man loses selling price of 4 candles. The numerical value of profit percent and loss percent is equal and the cost price of candle is half of the cost price of pen. Find the ratio of selling price of candle to pen.
Solution -
10 * SP of candle - 3 * SP of pen = 10 * CP of candle --- equation 1
10 * SP of pen - 4 * SP of candle = 10 * CP of pen --- equation 2
Applying elimination method, we get
-56 * SP of pen = -50 * CP of pen + 20 * CP of candle --- equation 3
Let CP of pen = 2u
Let CP of candle = 1u
Putting them in equation 3, we get
SP of pen = 10 / 7 u --- equation 4
Putting this in equation 1 and also put CP of candle = 1u, we get
SP of candle = 10 / 7 u --- equation 5
Clearly, equation 4 = equation 5
So, SP candle / SP of pen = 1 / 1 (why is this wrong?)
Because right answer is 3 / 2 at many websites.

Solution given by the vendor of the exam :
Because,
CP of candle = CP of pen / 2
Therefore,
10 * SP of candle - 3 * SP of pen = 5 * CP of pen --- equation 1
10 * SP of pen - 4 * SP of candle = 10 * CP of pen --- equation 2
So, from equation 1
Profit Percent = (3 * SP of pen / 5 * CP of pen) * 100 --- equation 3
Also, from equation 2
Loss Percent = (4 * SP of candle / 10 CP of pen) * 100 --- equation 4
According to question, equation 3 = equation 4
Therefore, SP of candle / SP of pen = 3 / 2

This is hard to read.  I suggest:  assign variable names of the usual sort to the quantities in question, then use the given data to write down equations connecting these.  After that, use those equations to solve for the unknowns you are asked about.

Also:  your condition on "percent" is somewhat ambiguous.  Percent of what?  Purchase Price?  To be precise, let $A,B$ be the selling/purchase prices for a  candle and $C,D$ be the selling/purchase prices for a pen.  Are you claiming that $\frac {A-B}B=\frac {D-C}D$?  Something else?

Both equations 2 are wrong. Pens are sold at a loss, so $$10 * \text{SP of pen} + 4 * \text{SP of candle} = 10 * \text{CP of pen}$$

The question implies the following four equations:
$$10  s_c = 10 c_c + 3 s_p\\
10 s_p = 10 c_p - 4 s_c\\
\frac{3 s_p}{10 c_c} = \frac{4 s_c}{10 c_p}\\
c_c = \frac{c_p}{2}$$

Let's ignore equation (3) completely, and just use the other three equations to find the ratio $s_p/s_c$.
Substituting (4) into (1) to eliminate $c_c$ we get:
$$10  s_c = 5 c_p + 3 s_p\\
10 s_p = 10 c_p - 4 s_c$$
Now eliminate $c_p$ by halving the second equation and subtracting it from the first:
$$10 s_c - 5 s_p = (5 c_p + 3 s_p) - (5 c_p - 2 s_c) \\
\implies 10 s_c - 5 s_p = 3 s_p + 2 s_c \\
\implies 8 s_c = 8 s_p \\ 
\implies s_c = s_p
\implies s_p/s_c = 1$$

Suppose that instead of leaving out equation (3), we use (3) but leave out equation (4).
$$10  s_c = 10 c_c + 3 s_p\\
10 s_p = 10 c_p - 4 s_c\\
\frac{3 s_p}{10 c_c} = \frac{4 s_c}{10 c_p}$$
Eliminate $c_c$ by substituting equation (3) into equation (1):
$$10  s_c = \frac{10 c_p \cdot 3 s_p}{4 s_c} + 3 s_p\\
10 s_p = 10 c_p - 4 s_c$$
Eliminate $c_p$ by substituting equation (2), and simplify:
$$10  s_c = \frac{(10 s_p + 4 s_c) \cdot 3 s_p}{4 s_c} + 3 s_p\\
\implies 40 s_c s_c = (10 s_p + 4 s_c) \cdot 3 s_p + 12 s_p s_c\\
\implies 40 s_c s_c = 30 s_p s_p + 12 s_p s_c + 12 s_p s_c\\ 
\implies 30 s_p^2 + 24 s_p s_c - 40 s_c^2 = 0\\
\implies 15 s_p^2 + 12 s_p s_c - 20 s_c^2 = 0$$
Let $r=\frac{s_p}{s_c}$ be the ratio we want to calculate. From the above equation we get:
$$ 15 r^2 + 12 r - 20 = 0$$
This has the solution
$$r = \frac{\sqrt{1344}-12}{30} = \frac{\sqrt{336}-6}{15} \approx 0.82202$$

Clearly these equations contradict each other, and there is no solution that satisfies all these equations simultaneously.
If this question was set on an exam, it should be declared void.

hey @Jaap I have added the solution given by the vendor of the exam, please have a look on that and give your precious insights if any

@rajrajput They're wrong. The equations contradict each other so you can get any value for the ratio depending on how you eliminate the variables. I showed what you get if you only use equations (1)(2)(3) or only use equations (1)(2)(4). If you use (1)(2) plus equations (3) and (4) in some other proportion, then you get other answers. None of these values are correct because there is no solution that satisfies all these equations simultaneously (except maybe when everything is zero).
